# Different examples for same model in swagger

Tags: swagger, api-design, swagger-editor

I'm trying to create an example in the request portion of my Swagger file. In the (heavily simplified) snippet below my request is describing the relationship between a patient and a clinician. Both these entities use the same `Identifier` model.

However, I can't seem to work out how to pass in example data that would be different for the `patientIdentifier` and the `clinicianIdentifier` while still making using of the common `Identifier` model. The snippet I've posted is syntactically correct, but obviously in example data will be the same for both Identifiers, which is far from ideal.

I realise I can just extract the fields from the `Identifer` model and copy them to the `patientIdentifier` and `clinicianIdentfier` without too much effort in this case, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

```
Relationship:
  properties:
    patientIdentifier:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'
    clinicianIdentifier:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'

Identifier:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      example: "Jane Doe"
    group:
      type: string
      example: "WD7"
```

If someone could point me in the right direction with something along the lines of documentation or an example that does this, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why I got hit with the downvote - happy to change/add/remove something if it helps - but I don't actually know what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to provide a schema-level example for `Relationship`. Schema-level examples take precedence over property-level examples.

```
Relationship:
  type: object
  properties:
    patientIdentifier:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'
    clinicianIdentifier:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'
  example:
    patientIdentifier:
      id: Jane Doe
      group: WD7
    clinicianIdentifier:
      id: Bob Smith
      group: ABCDE
```

Note that property-level examples for `patientIdentifier` and `clinicianIdentifier` won't work because when using a `$ref`, any siblings of a `$ref` are ignored.

```
# This won't work - examples will be ignored

Relationship:
  type: object
  properties:
    patientIdentifier:

      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'
      example:
        id: Jane Doe
        group: WD7

    clinicianIdentifier:

      $ref: '#/definitions/Identifier'
      example:
        id: Bob Smith
        group: ABCDE
```

Comment: Ahah! Did not realise you could do this. This was along the lines of what I was looking for. Thank you :)